# What is the name of the person who replaced Mark Shuttleworth as CEO of Canonical in 2009?

Tags: canonical

What is the name of the person who replaced Mark Shuttleworth as CEO of Canonical (the main developer of Ubuntu) in 2009?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Her name is Jane Silber.
Side note: Mark Shuttleworth returned to being CEO again in July 2017.